# Reading mailing addresses of varying length from a text file using regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text-files, generator

I am trying to read a text file and collect addresses from it. Here's an example of one of the entries in the text file:

```
Electrical Vendor                                                                                    Contact:        John Smith                                                              Phone #:        123-456-7890
              Address:              1234 ADDRESS ROAD                                                           Ship To:
                                    Suite 123                                                                                    ,
                                    Nowhere, CA United States 12345
              Phone:                234-567-8901                                       E-Mail:                  john.smith@gmail.com
              Fax:                  345-678-9012                                       Web Address:             www.electricalvendor.com
              Acct. No:             123456                                                   Monthly Due Date:                                Days Until Due
              Tax ID:                                                                                                   Fed 1099 Exempt                                 Discount On Assets Only
              G/L Liab. Override:
              G/L Default Exp:
              Comments:
                                   APPROVED FOR ELECTRICAL THINGS
```

I cannot wrap my head around how to search for and store the address for each of these entries when the amount of lines in the address varies. Currently, I have a generator that reads each line of the file. Then the `get_addrs()` method attempts to capture markers such as the `Address:` and `Ship` keywords in the file to signify when an address needs to be stored. Then I use a regular expression to search for zip codes in the line following a line with the `Address:` keyword. I think I've figured out how successfully save the second line for all addresses using that method. However, in a few addresses,es there is a suite number or other piece of information that causes the address to become three lines instead of two. I'm not sure how to account for this and I tried expanding my `save_previous()` method to three lines, but I can't get it quite right. Here's the code that I was able to successfully save all of the two line addresses with:

```
import re


class GetAddress():
    def __init__(self):
        self.line1 = []
        self.line2 = []
        self.s_line1 = []
        self.addr_index = 0
        self.ship_index = 0
        self.no_ship = False
        self.addr_here = False
        self.prev_line = []
        self.us_zip = ''

    # Check if there is a shipping address.
    def set_no_ship(self, line):
        try:
            self.no_ship = line.index(',') == len(line) - 1
        except ValueError:
            pass

    # Save two lines at a time to see whether or not the previous 
    # line contains 'Address:' and 'Ship'.
    def save_previous(self, line):
        self.prev_line += [line]

        if len(self.prev_line) > 2:
            del self.prev_line[0]

    def get_addrs(self, line):
        self.addr_here = 'Address:' in line and 'Ship' in line
        self.po_box = False
        self.no_ship = False
        self.addr_index = 0
        self.ship_index = 0
        self.zip1_index = 0

        self.set_no_ship(line)
        self.save_previous(line)

        # Check if 'Address:' and 'Ship' are in the previous line.
        self.prev_addr = (
            'Address:' in self.prev_line[0]
            and 'Ship' in self.prev_line[0])

        if self.addr_here:
            self.po_box = 'Box' in line or 'BOX' in line
            self.addr_index = line.index('Address:') + 1
            self.ship_index = line.index('Ship')

            # Get the contents of the line between 'Address:' and
            # 'Ship' if both words are present in this line.
            if self.addr_index is not self.ship_index:
                self.line1 += [' '.join(line[self.addr_index:self.ship_index])]

            elif self.addr_index is self.ship_index:
                self.line1 += ['']

        if len(self.prev_line) > 1 and self.prev_addr:
            self.po_box = 'Box' in line or 'BOX' in line
            self.us_zip = re.search(r'(\d{5}(\-\d{4})?)', ' '.join(line))
            if self.us_zip and not self.po_box:
                self.zip1_index = line.index(self.us_zip.group(1))

            if self.no_ship:
                self.line2 += [' '.join(line[:line.index(',')])]

            elif self.zip1_index and not self.no_ship:
                self.line2 += [' '.join(line[:self.zip1_index + 1])]

            elif len(self.line1) > 0 and not self.line1[-1]:
                self.line2 += ['']


# Create a generator to read each line of the file.
def read_gen(infile):
    with open(infile, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            yield line.split()


infile = 'Vendor List.txt'
info = GetAddress()

for i, line in enumerate(read_gen(infile)):
    info.get_addrs(line)
```

I am still a beginner in Python so I'm sure a lot of my code may be redundant or unnecessary. I'd love some feedback as to how I might make this simpler and shorter while capturing both two and three line addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8ybpmm/reading_mailing_addresses_of_varying_length_from/) and [u/Binary101010](https://www.reddit.com/user/Binary101010) pointed out that the text file is a fixed width, and it may be possible to slice each line in a way that only selects the necessary address information. Using this intuition I added some functionality to the generator expression, and I was able to produce the desired effect with the following code:

```
infile = 'Vendor List.txt'

# Create a generator with differing modes to read the specified lines of the file.
def read_gen(infile, mode=0, start=0, end=0, rows=[]):
    lines = list()
    with open(infile, 'r') as file:
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            # Set end to correct value if no argument is given.
            if end == 0:
                end = len(line)
            # Mode 0 gives all lines of the file
            if mode == 0:
                yield line[start:end]
            # Mode 1 gives specific lines from the file using the rows keyword
            # argument.  Make sure rows is formatted as [start_row, end_row].
            # rows list should only ever be length 2.
            elif mode == 1:
                if rows:
                    # Create a list for indices between specified rows.
                    for element in range(rows[0], rows[1]):
                        lines += [element]
                # Return the current line if the index falls between the
                # specified rows.
                if i in lines:
                    yield line[start:end]

class GetAddress:
    def __init__(self):
        # Allow access to infile for use in set_addresses().
        global infile
        self.address_indices = list()
        self.phone_indices = list()
        self.addresses = list()
        self.count = 0

    def get(self, i, line):
        # Search for appropriate substrings and set indices accordingly.
        if 'Address:' in line[18:26]:
            self.address_indices += [i]
        if 'Phone:' in line[18:24]:
            self.phone_indices += [i]
        # Add address to list if both necessary indices have been collected.
        if i in self.phone_indices:
            self.set_addresses()

    def set_addresses(self):
        self.address = list()
        start = self.address_indices[self.count]
        end = self.phone_indices[self.count]
        # Create a generator that only yields substrings for rows between given
        # indices.
        self.generator = read_gen(
            infile,
            mode=1,
            start=40,
            end=91,
            rows=[start, end])
        # Collect each line of the address from the generator and remove
        # unnecessary spaces.
        for element in range(start, end):
            self.address += [next(self.generator).strip()]
        # This document has a header on each page and a portion of that is
        # collected in the address substring.  Search for the header substring
        # and remove the corresponding elements from self.address.
        if len(self.address) > 3 and not self.address[-1]:
            self.address = self.address[:self.address.index('header text')]

        self.addresses += [self.address]
        self.count += 1

info = GetAddress()

for i, line in enumerate(read_gen(infile)):
    info.get(i, line)
```